# Matlab - load results from parallel job that crashed

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have a parallel job that crashed, but I want to retrieve variables until the point before crashing.

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Parallel Computing Toolbox performs no automatic checkpointing during execution - you'd need to do this manually.